# Accessing current request inside JobConsumer {AEM 6.1}

Tags: aem, jobs, consumer

I am currently implementing a job consumer. I want to access the current request's resource resolver object inside the consumer class. However when I try to add the resolver object in payload map, the job doesn't start and it returns null when I try to add the job.

Kindly let me know if anyone has done this before.

Kasyap.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add the resolver - it will be closed anyway once the request is processed. What you could do is: store the user id in the job properties:

```
            Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
            properties.put("userId", resource.getResourceResolver().getUserID());
            jobManager.addJob(JOB_TOPICS, properties);
```

You could then instantiate a new resource resolver with the user's access rights when you are dealing with the job.